# Beautiful Soup puzzle with soup.find() method

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, find

I am learning Beautiful Soup and Python and in this context I am doing the "Baby names" exercise of the Google Tutorial on Regex using the set of html files that contains popular baby names for different years (e.g. baby1990.html etc). You can find this dataset if you are interested here: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/baby-names

The html files contain a particular table which store the popular baby names and whose html code is the following:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" summary="formatting">
<tr valign="top"><td width="25%" class="greycell">
<a href="../OACT/babynames/background.html">Background information</a>
<p><br />
&nbsp; Select another <label for="yob">year of birth</label>?<br />      
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi">
&nbsp; <input type="text" name="year" id="yob" size="4" value="1990">
<input type="hidden" name="top" value="1000">
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="">
&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="   Go  "></form>
</td><td>
<h3 align="center">Popularity in 1990</h3>
<p align="center">
<table width="48%" border="1" bordercolor="#aaabbb"
 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" summary="Popularity for top 1000">
<tr align="center" valign="bottom">
<th scope="col" width="12%" bgcolor="#efefef">Rank</th>
<th scope="col" width="41%" bgcolor="#99ccff">Male name</th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="pink" width="41%">Female name</th></tr>
<tr align="right"><td>1</td><td>Michael</td><td>Jessica</td> # Targeted row
<tr align="right"><td>2</td><td>Christopher</td><td>Ashley</td> # Targeted row
etc...
```

There is also another table in the html file that I do not want to capture and has the following html code.

```
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tbody>
  <tr><td class="sstop" valign="bottom" align="left" width="25%">
      Social Security Online
    </td><td valign="bottom" class="titletext">
      <!-- sitetitle -->Popular Baby Names
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#333366"><td colspan="2" height="2"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="graystars" width="25%" valign="top">
       <a href="../OACT/babynames/">Popular Baby Names</a></td><td valign="top"> 
      <a href="http://www.ssa.gov/"><img src="/templateimages/tinylogo.gif"
      width="52" height="47" align="left"
      alt="SSA logo: link to Social Security home page" border="0"></a><a name="content"></a>
      <h1>Popular Names by Birth Year</h1>September 12, 2007</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#333366"><td colspan="2" height="1"></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

In comparing the table Tags of the two tables I concluded that the unique characteristic of the targeted table -- the table I am trying to capture-- is the 'summary' attribute which appears to have the value 'formatting'.  Therefore I tried the following command:

```
right_table = soup.find("table", summary = "formatting")
```

However, this command failed to select the targeted table.
In contrast, the following command succeeded:

```
table = soup.find(summary="Popularity for top 1000")
```

Could you explain by looking at the html code why the first command failed and the second succeeded?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you parsing [this page](https://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/)?

Comment: @alecxe `requests.get()` fails for that url. Any idea why?

Comment: @MYGz what are you getting? (it works for me) Could it be a country restriction? (since it's the SSA of the United States)

Comment: @alecxe It's working. It was a typo I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I answered your question earlier, the code works.

And one more thing, `html.patser` is broken in python2, do not use it, use `lxml`.

Comment: Great! It finally worked. Lots of thanks!  But tell me why your command worked with summary = ""Popularity for top 1000", since summary = "formatting". I can not understand that.

Comment: @im7 there are two tag contains `summary`, just search the HTML code